# wp query order by date not ordering scheduled date correctly

Tags: wordpress

wp query order by date not ordering scheduled date correctly.
I have scheduled posts and I try to order by `date` `DESC` but it still shows some older posts first.

(Also tried 'orderby' => 'date' and 'publish_date')
My query:

```
$args = array(
      'post_type'       => 'post',
      'posts_per_page'  => '4',
      'orderby'         => 'post_date',
      'order'           => 'DESC',
    );
```

And in post I'm showing date `get_the_date()`, this function shows correctly when published but query orderby not working and pushing this post first.

Image:[Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj4kU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the 'order' param:

```
$params = array(
'post_type' =>'post',
'orderby'   => array(
  'date' =>'DESC',
  'menu_order'=>'ASC',
  /*Other params*/
 )
);
$query = new WP_Query($params);
```

Comment: Same issue. Didn't change anything at all..